RDP server slow on Fridays (?!)
One of our clients has an Windows 2019 RDP server that for some reason becomes very slow on Fridays. We reboot it and it's fine, but next Friday, again it slows down. There's nothing obvious in logs, task manager, resources are not running high. There are no scheduled tasks that run on Thursday or Friday morning that might be related.
Any ideas about how to diagnose this?
Thanks.

Have you tried to reboot it beforehand to see if the problem occurs next day, or moves to the next Thursday? (To see whether it's tied to Friday or is happens after a solid week of uptime.) Also, what do you mean by "slow"? Slow login? Slow application response?

When the RDP server is slow, is there unusually high CPU load on the server? Are there any network traffic spikes on the local gateway?

As an example, we did actually need to reboot it for a different issue on Thursday morning and sure enough, it was slow on Friday. When I say slow, in a remote session, applications are very slow to open, slow mouse response, generally slow to do everything, but there's no unusually high CPU utilisation, or RAM maxed out.

May that be a network issue then? What do the related metrics show (primarily RTT and bandwidth)? And yes, it's wise to evaluate the performance of the whole route: find the client closest to the server (which still displays the problem) and explore switches, the gateway, whatever is in between.
